Friend function cannot be called unless I define it before main
As the title states, one of the friend functions I have defined throws an error if I define it after main and call it. It only happens to one of the friend function specifically and the only difference between the problematic friend function and the others is that it takes no arguments.
This code throws an error saying thisYear() was not declared in the scope.
class Date{
    private:
        int day, month, year;

    public:
        Date() {day = 1; month = 1; year = 2023;}

        Date(int d = 4, int m = 11, int y = 2023){
            day = d;
            month = m;
            year = y;
        }

        void setYear(int y){year = y;}

        void print() const{
            cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl ;
        }

        friend void nextDay(Date d);
        friend void nextMonth(Date &d);
        friend void nextYear(Date *d);
        friend void thisYear();
};

int main(){
    // other code

    thisYear();

    return 0;
}

void nextDay(Date d) {d.day++;}
void nextMonth(Date &d) {d.month++;}
void nextYear(Date *d) {d->year++;}
void thisYear() {cout << "The current year is 2023" << endl;}

However when I define thisYear() before main, I get the intended output "The current year is 2023". Why aren't the other friend functions affected by being defined after main?
Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks.

Functions introduced by the friend declaration are not found by the ordinary lookup, only by the argument-dependent lookup. But thisYear doesn't take any arguments, so there are no associated namespaces for the argument-dependent lookup to search. The other three do take an argument, and are found in the namespace associated with the type of that argument - namely, the global namespace.

I like your explanation, but if you change the declaration to have a parameter int i, it still fails.

Dupe: can't find a friend function and A question about name lookup with friend function

@TimRoberts int is not a class-type so ADL can't work there. Change it to Date and it will start working.

If you don't want this behavior then forward declare the class, forward declare the friend functions, define the class and add the friendship to the previously declared functions, then define the functions at some later point.
